# Cannot connect to DB server

Tags: mysql

I have been getting this issue constantly while attempting to set up a database on another computer. I have tried looking up solutions, but nothing I have tried so far has worked, and I have no idea what is causing the issue.

> Cannot Connect to Database Server. Connection attempt failed for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password (NO) (YES)

The computer in question did have a previous version installed, which I uninstalled and re-installed a different (later) version.

- I have checked the compatibility (64-bit on a 64-bit OS)
- I have attempted to boot the server through the command window, following [this set of instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html), to no avail.

Comment: What's the command you're using in order to connect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to log on MySQL on CentOS 6.3 using root account from the domain and not localhost?](http://serverfault.com/questions/422333/how-to-log-on-mysql-on-centos-6-3-using-root-account-from-the-domain-and-not-loc)

Comment: @ItaiGanot I'm using the workbench, not the command line.

Answer (score 1):

The tags you chose are Linux related and the guide you attached is for Windows.
If Linux is your case, then follow these steps in order to reset your MYSQL password.

Log in as root and stop the mysql daemon. Now lets start up the mysql daemon and skip the grant tables which store the passwords.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Then run:

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

You should see mysqld start up successfully. If not, well you have bigger issues.

Now you should be able to connect to mysql without a password.
Open mysql with user `root`:

```
mysql --user=root mysql
```

Enter the next command in mysql:

```
mysql> update user set Password=PASSWORD('new-password') where user='root';
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> exit;
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I am looking for the Windows version. However my issue is that I can't even log in as root. I also don't have the command line, only the workbench.

Comment: When you say you don't have the command line do you mean that you can't access the Windows command line at all? If you can, the mysql command line shell should be somewhere like "C:\Program Files\MySQL[ver]\bin"